# Overlapping sprites in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have found this [game](http://bombermine.com), which runs on canvas.

How can they have 2 characters on the same position (in 1 canvas)?

They are probably updating game characters every second like this:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
for (i=0;i<players.lenght;i++){
   context.drawImage(player, player[i][x], player[i][y]);
}
```

With this code, if 2 players will have same position, 1 player will be invisible..

Is there any better way to draw all the players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the players may be in the same game, doesn't mean they see the same view :) (think of any FPS game you've played online)

However, your assumptions are valid. The code I added to your sample code simply adds your player as the last player in the array meaning you will always be show as on top in *your* game (regardless if there is 2 or 10 players)

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

// Move your player to the top
for (i=0;i<players.lenght;i++){
    if (players.isYou()) {
        var you = players.splice(i, 1);
        players.push(you);
    }
}

for (i=0;i<players.lenght;i++){
    context.drawImage(player, player[i][x], player[i][y]);
}
```